# How to fetch data with EF one to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to fetch data with EF on one to many relationship.
i.e if i have a table name Person(personID as primary key) and another table name streetLivedIn(personID as foreign key).
Now i force my controller method to pass an object of type person

```
var persons=db.persons();
return View(persons);
```

Now i want to display Person details along with street(i.e that what stored at streetLivedInTable) he/she lived at.
suppose i have an Entityset of person

```
public class Persons
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   //NAVIGATIONL PROP. 
   public virtual ICollection<streetLivedIn>{get;set}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the navigational property name is `Streets`.

```
public class Persons
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   //NAVIGATIONL PROP. 
   public virtual ICollection<streetLivedIn> Streets { get; set }
}
```

Then you can use the `Include` method to eager load this property.

```
var persons = db.persons.Include("Streets");
return View(persons);
```

You can display this in various ways. Eg

```
@foreach (var person in Model)
{
     <div>@person.Name</div>

         @foreach (var street in person.Streets)
         {
               <div>@street.Name</div>
         }
}
```

Or you can use the `WebGrid`, `MvcContrib Grid`, etc

Comment: then how to display it on my view (like there is single entry for multiple streets) html.displayfor(model.name) and html.displayfor(model.streets)

Comment: i.e single person may hold multiple street then how it would be possible to display data from these two table in a single ViewTable

Comment: i already tried your code in case of many to one relationship and it works fine with it but in one to many relationship it is not working

Comment: one thing more "I am able to access streets property without using Include in my action" Whats that "early loading"??( I am very new to this tech. so please don mind if i am asking you silly things )

Comment: @Gimmebrkk It will eager load the `Streets` property. Otherwise Entity framework will issue additional query to the database for each person entity. Check [Select N+1](http://efprof.com/Learn/Alerts/SelectNPlusOne)

Comment: suggest me some useful link from where i can make myself ready to work with EF query model (if possible for u)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to expose the Entity Framework data model directly to the view, and instead do a conversion to business objects you create, I would simply iterate the EF datamodel with a double foreach loop. Entity Framework creates the one-to-many-references for you using containment - why not take advantage of that.

I prefix the EF-generated classses with "Ef" for clarity.

```
var personList = new List<Person>();
foreach (var efPerson in EfPersons)
{
    var person = new Person
    { 
        Name = efPerson.Name,
        StreetsLivedIn = new List<StreetLivedIn>();
    }
    foreach (var efStreet in efPerson.EfStreetsLivedIn)
    {
        var street = new StreetLivedIn { Name = efStreet.Name; }
        person.StreetsLivedIn.Add(street);
    }
    personList.Add(person);
}
return View(personList);
```

Comment: Note that if you do NOT mind exposing the EF object model to the View, the two lines of code in your question is the answer - you iterate the objects directly in the View.